# Javascript to enable, disable drop down menu in JSP file having Java code only, no HTML directly

Tags: javascript, jsp

Let me introduce the design.

Each field in a JSP is made by a `Map`.
The label name, the input type (drop down or other), the input values, the default values, etc are added to the `Map`, say `Map nameAttributes`.
There is another class, `GeneralWriter writer`, to which I do not have access, which takes the values from `Map`, parses them and writes the proper HTML code.

After writing the Map, `writer.writeSelectBox(nameAttributes);` is called.

Now, the requirement is:
There is a drop-down menu, depending upon its selected value, some other drop-down menus are disabled (shown in UI, but not modifiable) or enabled.
Since, I am not writing HTML code for the added field, I can not write the function call events to do my job.

I have observed that a JS function is called on `onMouseOut` event from the fields, as seen in `"View Source"`.
So I thought I might write my code there to check the field value and impact other drop-down menus.
But if I write `alert` in the JS function (just to check), it won't alert me, means the function is not called and I can not write the enable/disbale code.

Is there any way to achieve the job. The enabling and disabling should depend on what user selects in one of the drop downs.

Sample code:

```jsp
<%
Map nameAttr = new HashMap();   
nameAttr.put(GeneralConst.INPUT_MESSAGE, Const.MSG_FIELD_NAME);
//.....

writer.writeAllSelectBox(nameAttr);
%>
```

Urgent help needed, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In View Source of the JSP page, its clear that for some fields onChange and onMouseOut events etc. were added, and in the `GeneralWriter` class, those things were being written out to the out stream as follows

```
out.println("<td nowrap><select name=" + strName);
out.println(" style=\"width:" + strWidth + "px\"");
out.println(" onChange ="+onChange);
```

So, I added my own method there rather than using existing code and introduced the onChange event. The "`onChange`" variable that you see (the right one) is of `java.lang.String` type and this had to be passed from the JSP itself, as to what behavior I want or which particular function to call for a particular JSP.

Now I added the following in JSP

```
<body>
  <script>
    window.onload = setModeForPara2('MEMBERTYPE','MEMBERSTATE','CKSTATUS') ;
    function resetevent(uri){
      setModeForPara2('MEMBERTYPE','MEMBERSTATE','CKSTATUS') ;
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

where the parameters are the names of the drop down menus, and `setModeForPara2()` is a JS function to disable/enable as my requirement was stated in original post. It checks if MEMBERTYPE is 0, then render disabled state and gray color to MEMBERSTATE and CKSTATUS drop-down menus, else enable them and remove gray color.
The `resetevent(uri)` is also a JS function called when the Reset button is clicked to render the disabled state to the State and Status fields.

So that way, `setModeForPara2()` function is called whenever:
1. the page is loaded,
2. the value of first drop-down (MEMBERTYPE) is changed, and
3. the Reset button is clicked.

Resolved.